# How do you export a .cou file without opening the Attribute Table?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, export, import, address

We sometimes receive .cou files which are essentially just .csv files that contain address data, UPRNs etc. for processing.

As I have access to QGIS in my organization I was wondering how to produce these files myself but I couldn't find anything when looking up .cou files.

If possible I'm looking for a way to export this file without having to open up the Attribute Table as it contains around 70,000 rows of addresses

Comment: Export as different file format? Are you copy-pasting it to Excel?

Comment: I suspect a `.cou` is a change only update file - you need to know which of your features have changed to produce one

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your .cou file are structured exactly as a standard CSV, you could just export as CSV
(right click on your layer then export > save as... and choose CSV as the export format). After export you just have to rename the resulting file by changing the .csv by .cou (you can't directly name it with a .cou extension as QGIS will automatically add the .csv extension resulting in a .cou.csv file)